# How can I calculate a cumulative median for only some of the data in Polars?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, median, python-polars

I receive new grouped data each day. For each new datum, I need to calculate the new cumulative median of the entire group. But doing this over all data takes far too long. Even doing it over all data in just the groups with new data takes too long. Is there some way to use Polars to calculate these cumulative medians only for the new data but still be able to make use of all the data in the calculation?

The documentation advises against visiting all elements in `cumulative_eval()`, so I am open to alternatives that would be faster.

The following code calculates the cumulative medians for all data, including the old data.

```
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "group":  [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
        "value":  [20, 40, 30, 2, 4, 3, 200, 400, 300],
        "median": [20, 30, 30, 2, 3, None, 200, None, None]
    }
)

df.with_columns(
    pl.col("value")
    .cumulative_eval(pl.element().median())
    .over("group")
    .alias("median")
)
```

I can use filters to operate on only the groups with new data, but it still recalculates the cumulative medians for all data in those groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it not a [`.rolling_median()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.rolling_median.html)?

```
df.with_columns(
    pl.col("value")
      .rolling_median(window_size=df.height, min_periods=1)
      .over("group")
      .alias("median")
)
```

```
shape: (9, 3)
┌───────┬───────┬────────┐
│ group ┆ value ┆ median │
│ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---    │
│ i64   ┆ i64   ┆ f64    │
╞═══════╪═══════╪════════╡
│ 0     ┆ 20    ┆ 20.0   │
│ 0     ┆ 40    ┆ 30.0   │
│ 0     ┆ 30    ┆ 30.0   │
│ 1     ┆ 2     ┆ 2.0    │
│ 1     ┆ 4     ┆ 3.0    │
│ 1     ┆ 3     ┆ 3.0    │
│ 2     ┆ 200   ┆ 200.0  │
│ 2     ┆ 400   ┆ 300.0  │
│ 2     ┆ 300   ┆ 300.0  │
└───────┴───────┴────────┘
```

Comment: Hi @jqurious, I am curious if there are advantages for using df.height vs pl.count ? pl.count would have the advantage that it works for lazyframes

Comment: Hey @Luca, `window_size=` doesn't accept expressions unless I am mistaken?

Comment: @Luca From what I understand, pandas calls this `.expanding()` e.g. `.groupby(...)['value'].expanding().median()` but I couldn't find a polars equivalent for this.

Comment: good point, if windows_size does not allow for expressions then we need a df.height. I want add a GitHub issue for this, an expression for the windows size would be useful in case like this so we can : 1- use in lazy mode 2- refer to the size of the group

Comment: i have not use expanding in Pandas before, is that the equivalent of implode ?

Comment: @Luca `.expanding()` in pandas is the same as rolling in polars with an "unbounded" window size (this answer attempts to use `df.height` for unbounded). e.g. `pd.DataFrame(dict(id=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5])).expanding().agg(lambda row: [print(row.to_list()), 0][-1])` - You can also get the same windows with `.cumulative_eval()` in polars as OP showed, but that is a much more expensive operation. https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/7292

Comment: I didn't think I could use rolling_median, because of the parameters. But it makes sense with the arguments provided. Thanks!